# Discord.js Bot. Special answer when author mentions himself

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make special reply when user uses command, like:
if user used command + mentioned someone, bot replies:
'you did *something* with **username**'.
I wrote code for this and it works, but i want bot special reply, if user mentions himself like:
command + message author mention
'how you even imagine to do that with yourself uh'
i'm new at javascript, i don't sure that this question was not posted before.
Sorry for grammar also (non-native language).
Thanks for support!

Comment: Do you mean like for example the author is called user1 and some other user is called user2. When user1 does (if command is !) `!command user2`, the bot replies `'you did something with username'` and when user1 does `!command user1` The bot replies `how you even imagine to do that with yourself uh`?

Comment: Yes, like that.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to verify if the id of the author is equal to the mentioned user, here is a suggestion:

```js
let reply = "";
let mentionedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
if (message.author.id === mentionedUser.id) {
    reply = "How you even imagine to do that with yourself uh";
} else {
    reply = `You did something with ${mentionedUser.username}`;
}
message.channel.send(reply);
```